# PHP security forms _POST

Tags: php, security, post

I have a few questions about security using PHP, I dont want to use sessions so I am using POST to authenticate user from page to page, so:-

1) If I have a register form using method='POST' obviously I would need to filter out the data when its been sent to check if its valid and I also need SSL (https) on that page. Now just for register form which is very small ie name, email, password would filter checks and https be enough security just for this stage. I also have a captcha on register form to avoid spam.

2)Is it ok to send data like userid value like(ie 123456) in a hidden POST field so I can determine the user in database that is sending data, to avoid having to use sessions etc. Possibly send email address as well but nothing like passwords or very sensitive info. I would obviously check if the format is right for user id using regular expression ie if its x number of digits, same thing if posting email address. 
The reason I would send userid value and email address is so when user posts data in form after say register/login in they can fill out forms and I add a few hidden fields along with form to identify what user by using the email add and user id hidden value posted, they both have to be correct in mysql query otherwise error message, so even if tampered a hacker would have to guess right userid to email add. 
Also if the pages have ssl would this make be ok.

Hope this makes sense? 
Thanks

Comment: You should definitely use sessions and not hidden fields to indicate the user.

Comment: Why don't you want to use sessions?

Comment: Numeric user ids are by definition easy to guess. When you want to avoid PHPs session handling function, you will have to micromanage your own (e.g. new DB table associating random session hash with user id).

Comment: ie: *Do not trust the client* not to lie to you about the user ID, email, etc etc etc.  That stuff should be server-side only, unless you're also passing auth info each time as well -- which opens up a whole other can of worms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is by definition insecure, hijacking a session would be as easy as changing the value of the hidden form. If you know the UserId of another user, changing it into that value would make your application think that person is logged in.

I'm not sure what your reasons are to not use sessions, you should definitely reconsider.